# problems reinstalling apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apt

I uninstalled apache2 on debian 5 64bit. Then I removed `/etc/apache2` and reinstalled apache again. That folder is still missing and I have no idea how to get the apache files back (with modules and etc).

How do I restore everything?

Comment: What package did you exactly remove?
And if you do dpkg -l | grep apache?

Comment: Debian does not install apache2 in /var/ . For example, you will find the modules in /usr/lib/apache2/modules (If you used official .deb packages)

Comment: i meant /etc/apache2. doing `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` ATM causes the error `/etc/init.d/apache2: line 44: /etc/apache2/envvars: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cpf's idea should work, but, the config files are in the `apache2.2-common` package, not in the `apache2` package.

You can check what package owns a file with dpkg.

```
dpkg -S /etc/apache2/envvars
apache2.2-common: /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Answer (score 4):

You might try to completely remove (purge) apache, clean the local archives, and try to install it again:

```
# aptitude purge apache2
# aptitude clean
# aptitude install apache2
```

Comment: No luck. 7 more to go..